# Edit PHP file in Wordpress programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to edit a few PHP codes lines in my Wordpress theme files with a snippet of PHP code, though I am stuck and have been struggling to do this for a while with this code.

I have been trying to tweak this piece of code to do the job but unfortunately without luck.

```
function update_GTour_theme_files()
{
    $new_update = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php");
    $new_update = preg_replace('/$page_menu_transparent = 1/','$page_menu_transparent = 0',$new_update);
    $new_update = preg_replace('/$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 1/','$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0',$new_update);
    file_put_contents (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php", $new_update);

    if ( file_exists (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php") && is_writable (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php") ){

    update_GTour_theme_files();
    echo '</br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Changes were applied successfully.</span>';
    }

    else { 
    echo '</br><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Error occured while applying the changes.</span>';

    }   
}
```

I am expecting that this code should replace some text as illustrated in the file with the described path but it doesn't work.

Comment: _it doesn't work_ does not help much in solving your problem - do you get any error message(s)?

Comment: why are you doing this instead of directly editing the code online or in local text-editor?  and to me it looks like you're creating an infinite loop by calling the function again inside the if()

Comment: Whenever I call the function via a form button, the function doesn't do the desired result which is replacing the text. @jibsteroos

Comment: @Beatroot This piece of code is only a small part of long routine to change multiple files. It would be faster and easier to run a single code to apply many changes to multiple files in no time.

Comment: You should start debugging.

Comment: So, what does happen exactly when you run the function - when / where does the code deviate from the expected outcome and how?

Comment: `update_GTour_theme_files();` why are you calling this recursively it takes no arguments has fixed filenames, trying to have fun with infinite recursion?  Are you even calling it from the "form" as you said, because this **should** crash your browser, maybe even the server.  Because of the recursion.

Comment: `Whenever I call the function via a form button, the function doesn't do the desired result which is replacing the text` - well I hope not seeing as it just calls itself infinite number of times..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do I start... let me count the ways.

```
function update_GTour_theme_files()
{
    $new_update = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php");
    $new_update = preg_replace('/$page_menu_transparent = 1/','$page_menu_transparent = 0',$new_update);
    $new_update = preg_replace('/$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 1/','$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0',$new_update);
    file_put_contents (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php", $new_update);

    if ( file_exists (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php") && is_writable (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php") ){

    update_GTour_theme_files();
    echo '</br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Changes were applied successfully.</span>';
    }

    else { 
    echo '</br><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Error occured while applying the changes.</span>';

    }   
}
```

Lets see when you run this it does:

```
 file_put_contents (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php", $new_update);
```

Then it checks:

```
 if ( file_exists (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php") && is_writable (__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php") ){

    update_GTour_theme_files();
    echo '</br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Changes were applied successfully.</span>';
}
```

Which is obviously true, or we would have gotten some errors already.  So that is basically always true.  Which means you call this `update_GTour_theme_files();` itself again.  Repeat the above steps a infinite number of times.

So that is obviously wrong.  If you are calling this I would expect your browser to lockup.

**So lets fix this up (single file):**

```
function update_GTour_theme_files($file)
{
     //fail early
    if (!file_exists ($file) || !is_writable ($file) ) die("File $file Does not exists or is not writable");

    $new_update = file_get_contents($file);
    $new_update = preg_replace('/\$page_menu_transparent\s*=\s*1;/','$page_menu_transparent = 0;',$new_update);
    $new_update = preg_replace('/\$grandtour_page_menu_transparent\s*=\s*1;/','$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0;',$new_update);

    if(file_put_contents ($file, $new_update)){
       echo '</br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Changes were applied successfully.</span>';
    }else{ 
       echo '</br><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Error occured while applying the changes.</span>';
    }   
}

update_GTour_theme_files(__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/header.php");
```

This will only update the one file, to do more then that you need to use `scandir`, `glob` or SPL `DirectoryIterator / FilesystemIterator`.

PS your "main" or "big" problem (besides the recursion) is right here:

```
$new_update = preg_replace('/$page_menu_transparent = 1/','$page_menu_transparent = 0',$new_update);
$new_update = preg_replace('/$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 1/','$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0',$new_update);
```

These `$` in `/$page_menu_transparent` are not escaped so the are treated as REGEX. Which means they match the end of the string, which makes no sense.  I also added some vaiable space `\s*=\s*` and the `;` semi-colon otherwise `$page_menu_transparent = 1345;` will become `$page_menu_transparent = 0;`.  This may have some impact if it's in `()` or an array etc.  (anything without the `;`)

**For all files in a given folder and it's subfolders**

```
function update_GTour_theme_files($dir)
{
    if (!file_dir($dir) || is_writable ($dir) ) die("Dir $dir Does not exists or is not writable");

    $Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
                        $dir,
                        RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS|RecursiveDirectoryIterator::UNIX_PATHS
                    )
                );

    foreach($Iterator as $fileInfo){
        if($fileInfo->isDir() || $fileInfo->getExtension() != 'php') continue;

        $file = $fileInfo->getPathname();

        $new_update = file_get_contents($file);
        $new_update = preg_replace('/\$page_menu_transparent\s*=\s*1;/','$page_menu_transparent = 0;',$new_update);
        $new_update = preg_replace('/\$grandtour_page_menu_transparent\s*=\s*1;/','$grandtour_page_menu_transparent = 0;',$new_update);

        if(file_put_contents ($file, $new_update)){
           echo '</br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Changes were applied successfully.</span>';
        }else{ 
           echo '</br><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Error occured while applying the changes.</span>';
        }   
    }
}

update_GTour_theme_files(__DIR__ . "/../../themes/grandtour/");
```

This uses `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` so it should look through all sub folders.

But this is **all untested** so be very careful.  If you **mess your files** up don't come blaming me, you were warned.

That said Enjoy~